# Twilio whatsapp message fails even when matches the approved template

Tags: twilio, whatsapp

I am trying to send a whatsapp message via Twilio Business Account, from a number my company has registered via twilio and configured to be a sender.
In the Twilio logs, I see error 63016 message not in template, even though I double-checked every word and spacing to see that my message **matches the approved template**

some code to help:

```
def send_message(phone, template_message):
try:
    message = twilio_client.messages.create(
        body=template_message,
        from_=f'whatsapp:{MY_SENDER_NUMBER}',
        to=f'whatsapp:{phone}'
    )
except TwilioRestException as e:
    return False, e.msg
return True, ''
```

this completes with no error and results in this log line in twilio

```
From,To,Body,Status,SentDate,ApiVersion,NumSegments,ErrorCode,AccountSid,Sid,Direction,Price,PriceUnit
```

"whatsapp:+XXXXXXXXXXXX","whatsapp:+XXXXXXXXXXXX","MY MESSAGE THAT MATCHES THE TEMPLATE,
WITH SOME NEWLINES!
AND some characters like '' and ,
",UNDELIVERED,2021-04-11T07:58:32Z,"2010-04-01",1,**63016**,XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx,XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx,"
outbound-api",0.0,USD

note: if I open my whatsapp and sends the sender a message, then if I run this code again it will work and I will see that message (as that message does not have to match a template for a 24-hr window).

Comment: Sounds like you need to open a Twilio support ticket which you can do via the Twilio Console (upper right, under ? - Submit a Ticket), to determine why the approved WhatsApp template is not working as expected. If you match the template, it should allow you to initiate a conversation outside the 24 hour free form window.

Comment: @Alan thanks yes it was a matter of '\n' that was missing :) IMO twilio should go the extra mile and deliver the approved text as one-liner string with the non-printable characters or even as python string instead of relaying on my copy&paste skills :)

Answer (score 1):

After help from Twilio support, it was a missing '\n' in the message that I was trying to send, that caused the message not to match the template.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but was due to just a simple whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

In our case, the white space was replaced by a special character which was a looking like a whitespace.

[image]

Comment: How is this all a good experience for developers. Hope they fix this

Answer (score 0):

A slight change in WhatsApp template can cause this error. I would recommend below mentioned guidelines.

1. Copy Template as it is from "Message text" column of WhatsApp Template
2. Carefully use "\n" for newline.
3. Careful with whitespaces.
4. If you are using Python, here is an example:

   import os
   from twilio.rest import Client
   account_sid = 'account_id'
   auth_token = 'auth_token'
   client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

   body = "Hello Rakesh,\nThe amount of rupees 45000 is received by Kaveri Enterprise for 1BHK.\n\nOutstanding Amount: 12000.\n\nThanks,\nKaveri Enterprise"

   message = client.messages.create(
   body=body,
   from_='whatsapp:+193939992323',
   to='whatsapp:+910099038393'
   )
   print(message.sid)